# Como agregar mi función en el DOM?

Tags: javascript, array, poo, dom

Tengo una función que ya sirve, pero no se como agregar en una parte especifica del HTML

```
const coins = [
    {id: 'BTC', name: 'Bitcoin', price: 38875.6, imgUrl: 'https://cryptologos.cc/logos/bitcoin-btc-logo.svg?v=022'},
    {id: 'ETH', name: 'Ethereum', price: 2813.72, imgUrl: 'https://cryptologos.cc/logos/ethereum-eth-logo.svg?v=022'},
    {id: 'USDT', name: 'Tether', price: 1, imgUrl:'https://cryptologos.cc/logos/tether-usdt-logo.svg?v=022'},
    {id: 'BNB', name: 'Binance Coin', price: 371.14, imgUrl:'https://cryptologos.cc/logos/bnb-bnb-logo.svg?v=022'},
]

const main__section = document.getElementById('cotizaciones__container')

function createCoin(index){
    const createStruct = document.createElement('div')
    createStruct.style = 'display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr); grid-template-rows: 1fr; justify-items: start; align-items: center;'
    
    createStruct.innerHTML = 
        `   </div class="coin__main__container">
            <div class="coin__logo"><img src="${coins[index].imgUrl}"></div>
            <div class="coin__moneda">${coins[index].name}</div>
            <div class="coin__abreviatura">${coins[index].id}</div>
            <div class="coin__price">${coins[index].price}</div>
            </div>`;

    return document.body.appendChild(createStruct)
}

createCoin(2); //Tether
```

Pude recorrer bien el arreglo de objetos, ya pude hacer todo lo que quería hacer, pero no se como insertar en un `<section>` que se llama `cotizaciones__container`. En el script se llama `main__section`

Nada mas quiero que cuando se agregue, lo haga en el contenedor principal

Comment: Estás buscando algo como `main__section.appendChild(createStruct)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para mostrar en el HTML o DOM, hacia falta una sola línea de Javascript.

Para una mejor demostración, cree un archivo *CSS* aparte con algunos estilos adicionales que se puede agregar en el mismo script.

La línea de código que faltaba es:

```
main__section.innerHTML(createStruct)
```

Ó

```
main__section.appendChild(createStruct)
```

Un ejemplo completo:

```js
const coins = [ 
{
 id: 'BTC', 
 name: 'Bitcoin', 
 price: 38875.6, 
 imgUrl: 'https://cryptologos.cc/logos/bitcoin-btc-logo.svg?v=022'
},{
 id: 'ETH', 
 name: 'Ethereum', 
 price: 2813.72, 
 imgUrl: 'https://cryptologos.cc/logos/ethereum-eth-logo.svg?v=022'
},{
 id: 'USDT', 
 name: 'Tether', 
 price: 1, 
 imgUrl:'https://cryptologos.cc/logos/tether-usdt-logo.svg?v=022'
},{
 id: 'BNB', 
 name: 'Binance Coin', 
 price: 371.14, 
 imgUrl:'https://cryptologos.cc/logos/bnb-bnb-logo.svg?v=022'
},

];

function createCoin(index){ 
 
 const createStruct = document.createElement('div');  
 
 //createStruct.style = 'display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr); grid-template-rows: 1fr; justify-items: start; align-items: center;'; 
 
 createStruct.innerHTML = ` 
 <div class="coin__main__container"> 
  <div class="coin__logo">
   <img src="${coins[index].imgUrl}">
  </div> 
 <div class="coin__moneda">${coins[index].name}</div> 
 
 <div class="coin__abreviatura">${coins[index].id}</div> 
 
 <div class="coin__price">${coins[index].price}</div> 
 
 </div>`; 
 
 return document.body.appendChild(createStruct) 

} 

createCoin(2); //Tether

const main__section = document.getElementById('cotizaciones__container').innerHTML(createStruct)
```

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box
}

html,body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

body {
 min-height: 100vh;
 background-color: lightblue;
}

.coin__main__container {
 display: grid; 
 grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr); 
 grid-template-rows: 1fr; 
 justify-items: start;
 align-items: center;
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 min-height: 100px;
 background-color: rgba(47,47,98, 0.5)
}

.coin__logo {
 width: 100px;
 position: relative;
 margin: 1em;
}

.coin__logo img {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 object-fit: cover;
}

.coin__moneda {
 font-weight: bold;
 color: green;
}

.coin__abreviatura {
 font-style: italic;
}

.coin__price {
 font-weight: bold;
 color: red;
}
```

```html
<section id="cotizaciones__container">

</section>
```